# Javascript get the sum of each array seperate

Tags: javascript, arrays, xml, html-table

I've been trying to figure out how to perform this action properly and I'm sure I'm being an idiot (new to code here). I have a xml file (shown below), that I am parsing and attempting to build multiple tables for each data set based on the node "testset". The xml file will not change how it's designed, but will grow in how many "testsets" there are. I have the code below.

I currently have testspassed and testpassed showing the 2 arrays as I need, but I can't figure out how to get the sum of each array separate (and expect that there will be a unknown amount of arrays in the further) and then I have to write it to the table. The code below currently adds together both parts of the array in tests passed, I need to keep them separated. So I want the array set to be 137, 70. I am thankful for any help or suggestions.

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TestSets>
  <TestSet>
    <TestSetID>TestSet_iOS1</TestSetID>
    <Hardware>iPad Air 2</Hardware>
    <Version>iOS 8.3</Version>
    <Build>Pro 2.7.0.13 </Build>
    <Orientation>PORTRAIT</Orientation>
    <NumTestCases>46</NumTestCases>
    <NumTestScripts>17</NumTestScripts>
    <TotalTime>230891.363</TotalTime>
    <TestResults>
      <TestRun>
        <Date>24 Mar 2015 09:12:00</Date>
        <Hardware>iPad Air 2</Hardware>
        <Version>iOS 8.1.3</Version>
        <Build>2.7.0.607</Build>
        <Orientation>PORTRAIT</Orientation>
        <NumPassed>37</NumPassed>
        <NumFailed>31</NumFailed>
      </TestRun>
      <TestRun>
        <Date>27 Mar 2015 11:43:18</Date>
        <Hardware>iPad Air 2</Hardware>
        <Version>iOS 8.1.3</Version>
        <Build>Pro 2.7.0.615</Build>
        <Orientation>PORTRAIT</Orientation>
        <NumPassed>100</NumPassed>
        <NumFailed>25</NumFailed>
      </TestRun>
     </TestResults>
  </TestSet>
  <TestSet>
    <TestSetID>TestSet_iOS2</TestSetID>
    <Hardware>iPad Air 2</Hardware>
    <Version>iOS 8.1.3</Version>
    <Build>Pro 2.7.0.623</Build>
    <Orientation>LANDSCAPE</Orientation>
    <NumTestCases>38</NumTestCases>
    <NumTestScripts>9</NumTestScripts>
    <TotalTime>20800.255</TotalTime>
    <TestResults>
      <TestRun>
        <Date>30 Mar 2015 10:29:00</Date>
        <Hardware>iPad Air 2</Hardware>
        <Version>iOS 8.1.3</Version>
        <Build>2.7.0.615</Build>
        <Orientation>LANDSCAPE</Orientation>
        <NumPassed>34</NumPassed>
        <NumFailed>15</NumFailed>
      </TestRun>
      <TestRun>
        <Date>31 Mar 2015 20:00:02</Date>
        <Hardware>iPad Air 2</Hardware>
        <Version>iOS 8.1.3</Version>
        <Build>Pro 2.7.0.620</Build>
        <Orientation>LANDSCAPE</Orientation>
        <NumPassed>10</NumPassed>
        <NumFailed>19</NumFailed>
      </TestRun>
      <TestRun>
        <Date>02 Apr 2015 10:15:25</Date>
        <Hardware>iPad Air 2</Hardware>
        <Version>iOS 8.1.3</Version>
        <Build>Pro 2.7.0.623</Build>
        <Orientation>LANDSCAPE</Orientation>
        <NumPassed>26</NumPassed>
        <NumFailed>12</NumFailed>
      </TestRun>
    </TestResults>
  </TestSet>
</TestSets>
```

**Current Code**

```
 document.write("<table><tr><th><st>Test Set ID</st></th><th>Hardware</th><th>Op Sys Version</th><th>App Build</th><th>Orientation</th><th>Number of Test Passed</th><th>Number of Test Failed</th></tr>");
var x = xml.getElementsByTagName("TestSet");
var sum = 0;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    document.write("<tr class='dynamictable'><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TestSetID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Hardware")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Version")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Build")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    document.write("</td><td>");
    document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Orientation")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    var y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TestRun");
    var testspassed = [];
    var testsfailed = [];
    for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
        testspassed.push(y[j].getElementsByTagName("NumPassed")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        testsfailed.push(y[j].getElementsByTagName("NumFailed")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
    }

    for (var k=0; k<testspassed.length; k++){
    sum+=testspassed[k]<<0;   
}
console.log(sum);
```

}

Comment: did you tried [http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_transformation.asp) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the cleanest and best way but here's what I did to get it working:

```
document.write("<table><tr><th><st>Test Set ID</st></th><th>Hardware</th><th>Op Sys Version</th><th>App Build</th><th>Orientation</th><th>Number of Test Passed</th><th>Number of Test Failed</th></tr>");
      var x = xml.getElementsByTagName("TestSet");
      for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        testspassed = [];
        testsfailed = [];
        passedsum = 0;
        failedsum = 0;
        var y = x[i].getElementsByTagName("TestRun");
        for (j = 0; j < y.length; j++) {
          passed = (y[j].getElementsByTagName("NumPassed")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          failed = (y[j].getElementsByTagName("NumFailed")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
          passedsum += passed << 0;
          failedsum += failed << 0;
        }
        document.write("<tr class='dynamictable'><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("TestSetID")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Hardware")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Version")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Build")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(x[i].getElementsByTagName("Orientation")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(passedsum);
        document.write("</td><td>");
        document.write(failedsum);
        document.write("</td></tr>");
      }
```